# Declaring zero size vector

Tags: c

What does the following mean?

```
struct foo
{
...
char  bar[0];    // Zero size???
};
```

I asked my colleagues and they told me it's the same as writing `void* bar`.

As far as I know a C pointer is just a 4 byte variable (at least on a 32bit machine). How can the compiler know that bar[0] is a pointer (and thus 4 bytes long)? Is that just syntactic  sugar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your colleagues lied. (Probably not intentionally though so don't get mad at them or anything.)

This is called a flexible array member, and in C99 is written as `char bar[];`, and in C89 was written as `char bar[1];`, and which some compilers would let you write as `char bar[0];`. Basically, you only use pointers to the structure, and allocate them all with an amount of extra space at the end:

```
const size_t i = sizeof("Hello, world!");
struct foo *p = malloc(offsetof(struct foo, bar) + i);
memcpy(p->bar, "Hello, world!", i);
// initialize other members of p
printf("%s\n", p->bar);
```

That way, `p->bar` stores a string whose size isn't limited by an array declaration, but which is still all done in the same allocation as the rest of the `struct` (rather than needing the member to be a `char *` and need two `malloc`s and two `free`s to set it up).

Comment: Ah now I understand. In this way the structure instance is contained in a continuous memory area. If bar were a pointer then it would point to another memory chunk. Thus flexible arrays permit to copy the structure with a single memcopy for example. I found that structure in the Linux kernel and in fact a single memcopy is used to copy from kernel space to user space.

Comment: @happy_emi - In addition to a single `memcpy` (which is a big plus) it also only takes a single `malloc` (which can be relatively expensive, especially if it's the kind of object where you make a lot of them).

Comment: Of course.  (btw I meant copy_to_user, not memcpy. Just for the record.)

Answer (score 3):

Chris' answer is correct, but I'd probably allocate the object slightly differently.

```
int n = ...; // number of elements you want
struct foo *p = malloc(offsetof(struct foo, bar[n]));
```

then iterate over it with

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  p->bar[i] = ...;
}
```

The key point is that Chris' answer works since `sizeof(char)==1`, but for another type, you'd have to explicitly multiply by `sizeof *bar`.

Comment: I forget where I saw the `offsetof(struct foo, bar[n])` trick first but +1 for reminding me. It's a lot better than my version.

Comment: @Chris, perhaps [Raymond's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/08/26/220873.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

This should be a compiler-time error! Only dynamically allocated arrays can be allocated with 0 size.

Comment: Some (lazy?) compilers would let people declare flexible array members as `char bar[0];` before C99 standardized the `char bar[];` syntax. So this is probably not an error.

Answer (score 0):

An array will also be accessed via pointers (indices are implicit pointers).
So I suspect, if they tell you so, this will be interpreted like a pointer. As it’s a zero-length array it will probably point to the next value (I hope something follows in that struct?).

This is suspection, not knowledge. :)

It’s not how you would do anything though …
If they want a pointer they should use a pointer. If they can’t tell you why it’s there it shouldn’t be.

Comment: I thought to a label myself. But the field is declared at the bottom of the structure