# Why char name[0]?

Tags: c, char

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [zero length arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690718/zero-length-arrays)

Recently, I've been reading the FUSE source code and the `dirent struct` is defined as follows:

```
struct fuse_dirent
{
    __u64 ino;
    __u64 off;
    __u32 namelen;
    __u32 type;
    char name[0];
}
```

Can anyone explain what `name[0]` means here? What is it for? For padding and alignment?

Comment: Many duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690718/zero-length-arrays ;  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255193/declaring-zero-size-vector ;  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627364/zero-length-arrays-vs-pointers

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this "pattern" in Microsoft's code, usually when the struct in object's size is not known a priori.

You don't allocate it with the usual way, but you do something like:

```
struct fuse_dirent* data = malloc(sizeof(fuse_dirent) + ... );
```

then you can access the extra data by accessing `name` member.

Of course, this practice is not safe, so you have to pay extra attention.

Answer (score 0):

When this structure is allocated, some additional space will also be allocated at the end for storing a string. This way, the string can be accessed through fuse_dirent::name as if it were a "real" `char *` type. The reason for it being `[0]` is to not allocate any additional space in the `fuse_direct` "header".

An example:

```
fuse_dirent *d = malloc(sizeof(fuse_dirent) + 3);
strcpy(d->name, "hi");
printf(d->name); // will print "hi" to the console
```

Comment: Just a warning: 0-length arrays are actually illegal in C/C++, they are only supported by some compilers as their own extension.

Comment: yes,you're right,the code of fuse is also like that,Thank you very much.the fuse source code: struct fuse_dirent *dirent = (struct fuse_dirent*)buf;
 dirent->ino = stbuf->st_ino;
 dirent->off = off;
 dirent->namelen = namelen;
 dirent->type = (stbuf->st_mode & 0170000) >> 12;
 strncpy(dirent->name,name,namelen);