# Access memory through pointers to structures of pointers

Tags: c, pointers, structure

Suppose i have N bytes of contiguous memory:

```
char A[N];

| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
```

and I want to access the memory like this:

```
|__ _|__ _| | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
```

The first two blocks are 4 bytes long and the rest are 1 byte long. I want to create a structure based on this memory in order to easily access memory in that way.

I tried this way, but it doesn't work:

```
typedef struct {
    int *a,*b;
    char *c;
} mem;

mem *p;
p->a=(int*)A;
p->b=((int*)A+1);
p->c=((int*)A+2);
```

or

```
mem *p
p=(mem*)A;
```

And then access the elements using `*(p->a)`, `*(p->b)` and `*(p->c)`.

Can you suggest me a correct approach and explain to me why this doesn't work?

Comment: If ask about a problem you should really include a description of that problem in your question. "Does not work" is the worst possible problem description. If you don't say what goes wrong, how do you expect anybody to be able to help? What results do you get and what did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: What kind of values to you expect `p->a`, etc, to give? If you use an `int32`-like variable, endianness *could* be a problem.

Comment: Lundin correctly observed that portable code in this manner can be tricky, as you may have alignment issues.  Namely, the beginning of the N bytes must begin at a byte that is a multiple of `sizeof(int)`.  If not, you might have problems reading the first two `int`s of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(1)
 typedef struct {
     int a,b;
     char c[256]; // maximum length of `A`
 } mem;
#pragma pack(pop)

 mem *p = (mem*)A;
```

Comment: What if there are padding bytes inside the struct?

Comment: That works on a couple of compilers, but strictly speaking there are no guarantees. Anyway, as long as one is aware of the issue it is probably alright...

Comment: C++11 guarantees no padding in this particular situation, and I'd expect the same guarantee from C.  I don't know C nearly as well though.

Comment: Dave observes that this may break on targets that don't allow unaligned access, depending on how `A` is obtained.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do like this:

```
int* a;
int* b;
char* c;
char A[N] = {/* data goes here */};

a = (int*)A;
b = (int*)(A+sizeof(int));
c = A + 2*sizeof(int);
```

Please note however that typecast between different integer types like this isn't well-defined behavior in C. The code will be vulnerable to endianess, there's no telling where the signed bit will end up, it could all possibly result in a trap representation etc etc.

So unless your particular compiler guarantees what the result will be, the code can go haywire. And of course it is also non-portable.

**EDIT :** Please note that the above is more portable way than using a struct pointer, although the struct pointer looks more elegant. Because a struct may contain any number of padding bytes anywhere, so there are no guarantees that the struc pointer will realize that the memory pointed at is allocated adjacently.

Comment: At the same time, since this doesn't take padding into account, when he dereferences a field the compiler would pad, he'll be thrown under the SIGBUS

Comment: @Dave: Arrays cannot contain padding. The OP's requirement was "Suppose i have N bytes of contiguous memory.".

Comment: That's my point. If the data requires padding, which the array doesn't provide, SIGBUS.

Comment: @Dave Yeah, and...? That is the sole reason why I wrote this answer, while there were already two answers with struct implementations. I also pointed it out to the authors of those answers that padding may be an issue.

Comment: My point is that this isn't much more portable than a struct pointer, because the padding issue breaks both implementations.

Comment: @Dave: I don't understand you. Where in the code I posted can padding cause problems? There is nothing there which can contain any padding...

Comment: This is not a solution, i want to use a structure as i described in order to easily access the blocks of data.

Comment: @Lundin: maybe where Dave is saying "padding" he means "alignment"?  Yours could suffer alignment issues (although, so would all other answers thus far)

Comment: @MooingDuck exactly. In most cases, the compiler pads structs because of alignment issues. Wrong words on my part.

Comment: @flowerpower Then your only solution is to pick on of the struct examples, then go off to read the compiler documentation about padding and possible support for #pragma pack and similar mechanisms. Happy reading.

Comment: @MooingDuck Aah yes now I understand what he is trying to say. Well, none of this is really related to alignment. If the original data array isn't aligned, then all bets are off. If it is, then I don't see any issues with accessing it through int*. But as I wrote in my answer, any access of a char array like this isn't well-defined behavior, you are pretty much left on your own, with no guarantees from the C language.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to treat this block of memory - ie. as an integer type where endianness is important, or just as a block of 4 sequential bytes. If more-so the latter, this is how I would approach it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
   char block[4];
} block_of_4;

typedef struct {
   block_of_4 a;
   block_of_4 b;
   char c[1]; /* hack :) - more legal than "char c[0];" */
} mem;

int main(void)
{
   char A[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
   block_of_4 block1 = { { "1234" } };
   block_of_4 block2 = { { "9876" } };

   mem *p = (mem*) A;

   p->a = block1;
   p->b = block2;
   p->c[2] = '_';

   printf("%s\n", A);

   return 0;  
}
```

Output:

```
12349876ij_lmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

That's as long as the compiler decides to keep the elements of the `struct`s in order, and doesn't do any padding.

Comment: I believe flexible array members are written as `char c[];`? C99 6.7.2.1 §16. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255193/declaring-zero-size-vector).

Comment: @Lundin: Yeah that's right, however I prefer to stick to C89/C90. Speaking of which, `char c[0]` would be better as `char c[1]`.

Comment: Flexible array members were introduced in C99. C90 does not support them. I believe char c[1] is an acceptable work-around in C90 indeed.

Comment: @Lundin: Yeah that's my point, which is why I stick to the hack `char c[1]`.

Comment: @AusCBloke: I had to make minor alterations to make your code compile: http://ideone.com/D6KDL

Comment: @MooingDuck: It should compile fine without errors and warnings as **C** - http://ideone.com/6FOjv. C allows a terminator not to be added to the `char` array if the array isn't large enough (`block[4]`, 4 chars of `"1234"` without the `'\0'`). However, it won't compile as C++ because it always wants to add the NUL to the `char` array, and a `char[5]` won't fit in a `char[4]`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work, because the methods of storing a `BYTE` and `DWORD` in memory are different (in Intel architecture).
While `BYTE`s are stored consequentially, `DWORD`s are stored in reverse order.
So if you want to release say `1` as an integer (`DWORD`) from `A[0]`, then the `A` must be:

```
char A[]={1,0,0,0...}
```

As I see, there are already posted right approaches.

Comment: "`DWORD`s are stored in reverse order" more specifically on little-endian machines.