# Typedef works for structs but not enums, only in C++

Tags: c++, c, gcc, enums, typedef

I have the following code:

test_header.h:

```
typedef enum _test_enum test_enum;
enum _test_enum
{
    red,
    green,
    blue
};

typedef struct _test_struct test_struct;
struct _test_struct
{
    int s1;
    int s2;
    int s3;
};
```

test.c:

```
#include <test_header.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    test_struct s;
    s.s1=1;
    s.s2=2;
    s.s3=3;
    printf("Hello %d %d %d\n", s.s1, s.s2, s.s3 );
}
```

test_cpp.cpp:

```
extern "C"{
    #include <test_header.h>
}
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    test_struct s;
    s.s1=1;
    s.s2=2;
    s.s3=3;
    printf("Hello %d %d %d\n", s.s1, s.s2, s.s3 );
}
```

Notice how I am typedef'ing the struct and the enum the same way. When I compile in straight C with `gcc -I. test.c -o test` it works fine, but when compiled in C++ with `gcc -I. test_cpp.cpp -o test_cpp`, I get the following error:

```
./test_header.h:1:14: error: use of enum ‘_test_enum’ without previous declaration
```

So my question is twofold: why does this work in C but not C++, and why does the compiler accept the struct but not the enum?

I get the same behavior when declaring the struct above the enum. I'm using GCC 4.8.2.

Comment: *why does this work in C but not C++?* -- Simple answer: C and C++ are **different** languages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ISO C standard forbids forward references to `enum` types. I'm not completely sure, but I guess that this is the excerpt that confirms it:

> **6.7 Declarations**
>
> 1 [...]
>
> **Constraints**
>
> 2 A declaration shall declare at least a declarator (other than the
>     parameters of a function or the members of a structure or union), a
>     tag, or the members of an enumeration.
>
> 3 [...]

Please, if this is wrong, and you know which section exactly refers to the issue, correct me.

As a result, you are not allowed to use forward declarations of enumerations in C. Though, GCC allows it as an extension, but will certainly throw a warning if you enable `-Wpedantic` switch.

By the way, you could have written it like this:

```
typedef enum {
  red,
  green,
  blue,
} test_enum;
```

and it is perfectly fine according to standard, and thus will compile even with `-Wpedantic -Werror`.

Comment: can we have any reference of the standard? I mean which section of the standard?

Comment: A link to that part of the standard would be nice, I would like to know why structs are treated differently. 
Why is it enabled by default in C but not C++?

Comment: Updated, take a look.

Comment: I seriously don't understand what the standard is saying here. Can anyone explain this. Want to know...

Comment: @Nishith: Basically, it says that declaration of enumeration cannot be done without specifying its members, i.e. forward declaration simply cannot be done for `enum`.

Comment: Note: `-Wpedantic` (or `-pedantic`) sometimes only causes a warning for some extensions; to force GCC to treat every one as an *error* you can use **`-pedantic-errors`** (thanks to [hvd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551174/why-is-the-size-of-my-class-zero-how-can-i-ensure-that-different-objects-have-d/18551259#comment27289775_18551259)), in addition to `-std=`... (`c++11` for example).

Answer (score 6):

The enum is an integral type and the compiler chooses the exact type according to the range of values of the enumeration. So you can't do a forward declaration of an enum.

Comment: You can pre-define type of enum for compiler, for example by using `enum test_enum : int`. So you can do a forward declaration of enum.
Thanks for your comment, it made me realize __why__ I couldn't do a forward declaration, and then how to fix it.