# Return value of non-member std::empty overload for fixed-size arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, c++17

The [accepted] standards paper [N4280](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4280) adds several new non-member functions to be folded into C++17.

There are remarks indicating the proper return values for each of the new non-member functions, and in particular, the `std::empty` overload for fixed-size arrays confuses me. The paper suggests that the return value for that overload will always be `false`; that *all* fixed-sized arrays will never be empty.

Why would this be the case? To my knowledge it is possible (though perhaps useless) to have a zero-sized array, as in `int x[0];`, which I would call empty.

For reference, the particular overload I speak of is:

```
template <class T, size_t N> constexpr bool empty(const T (&array)[N]) noexcept;
```

Comment: If you compile with `-pedantic` on g++, you will actually get `ISO C++ forbids zero-size array`. Also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10353341/234175

Comment: @greatwolf - That would be it! Wasn't using `-pedantic` because I tested it quickly with ideone.com. Thanks!

Comment: I'd expect that the purpose of this overload is just to provide the unified container interface, that is to make arrays usable with `std::empty` just like any other container.

Comment: Indeed, the purpose is clear, I was just confused on the point mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will always return false simply because arrays can't be declared to contain zero elements.  From the C++11 standard (I don't have a more recent standard handy and I don't expect this will have changed anyway):

> In a declaration `T D` where `D` has the form
>
> `D1 [` *constant-expression<sub>opt</sub>* `]` *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>*
>
> ... If the *constant-expression* is present, it shall be an integral constant expression and its value shall be greater than zero. - §8.3.4 [dcl.array]

Therefore this overload would always return true in a conforming implementation.